# Suggestion for Desktop Application Design

Tags: user-interface, desktop-application

I am working on wireframes for desktop application, its collaboration system for paramedical staff like chatting and communication stuff.

Now i need to create GUI, Can anyone suggest me that if i make it in photoshop then what would be best practices or can anyone suggest me some other tools for GUI?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Mockups of a UI can be done in anything you want. Common tools are pen and paper, things like [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups), PowerPoint, Visio, Photoshop and whatever you can think of. I prototyped things in Visual Studio with WPF, too.

Most importantly I think that your mockups should *look* like they are mockups, not actual screenshots. Because people tend to fuzz over pixels when it looks like it could be an actual application screenshot. They tend to focus on the important details more when it's just hand-drawn.

Comment: Joey you are right i have created all the mockups using wire-framing tool now i have to present to my client how it will looks after development. **It is multi platform application so suggest me can i design it in Photoshop?**

Answer (score 1):

My tool is pretty popular for this: [MockupScreens](http://www.MockupScreens.com) - You can switch the "skins" on the fly (Mac, Windows, etc).

And here is the complete list of similar tools:
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools